# running 2 Webviews in a view

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm unable to run two web views at once I've tried playing with it but need some help... its not as simple as saying `View2` like in `Swift`.

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffb067"
tools:context=".FeedFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Feed Fragment" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/livefeed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="310dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/livestream"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" >

</WebView>

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
private WebView livestream;
private WebView livefeed;


public FeedFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view , Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    livestream = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.livestream);
    livestream.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    livestream.loadUrl("website1");

    livefeed = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.livefeed);
    livefeed.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    livefeed.loadUrl("website2");
}

}
```

One view is a video stream other is the notes for the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make  your layout scrollable and chnage the textview's height to  `wrap_content`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffb067"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Feed Fragment" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/livefeed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="310dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/livestream"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" >

    </WebView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I strongly recommend  that you read  [Google's a layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout) .